# Definition of zero dimensional locale

Tags: order-theory

In the article "Vietoris Locales and Localic Semilattices" the author (Johnstone) writes of a zero dimensional locale. However, he does not define the notion. I cannot find the definition anywhere, hence my question:

**Question:** can anybody give me a reference for the definition of a zero dimensional locale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not explicit in Johnstone's book "Stone Spaces" - see exercise in III 1.1 - but I would define a locale to be zero dimensional if every open $a$ (i.e. element of its frame) is the join of complemented opens $c \leq a$. (An open $c$ is complemented if there exists another open $b$ such that $c \vee b =1$ and $c \wedge b = 0$.)